# ServiceStack: Get list of all supported routes in current application

Tags: servicestack

Is it possible to get a list of the currently defined routes of a ServiceStack application? I'd rather not maintain one separately, but it would be nice to keep a list for documentation's sake (without parsing route attributes, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may take a look at the Routes property:

```
var restPaths = ((ServiceRoutes)AppHost.Instance.Routes).RestPaths;
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.
foreach (RestPath route in ((ServiceRoutes) host.Routes).RestPaths)

Comment: `RestPaths` is now a member of `AppHost`

Answer (score 3):

You can browse out to `operations/metadata` on your site.

http://razor.servicestack.net/operations/metadata

But I have noticed that it is pretty picky about how you decorate your service. For example, I have to be explicit about http verbs on the `Route` attributes.

I think this is why the routes don't show up for all of the operations in the above example.